# Symfony 4.3: FormType add extra "Entity" type

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a form to register a new `Number` so i've created a `NumberType`(code below). But on the top of the form it adds a field as bellow :

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" required="required" class="form-control">
```

**NumberType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('created_by', EmailType::class, [
            'label' => 'Email *',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'monadresse@mail.fr',
            )
        ])
        ->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Titre *'
        ])
        ->add('value', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Valeur *'
        ])
        ->add('source', UrlType::class, [
            'label' => 'Source *'
        ])
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
            'label' => 'Description',
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Description du chiffre proposé'                    
            )
        ])
        ->add('tags')
        ->add('recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class)
        ->add('send', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Envoyer'])
    ;
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
$number = new Number();
// Form creation
$form = $this->createForm(NumberType::class, $number);
```

When I call the url associated with my function in my controller I had an error which was saying

> Can't convert Number to string

So I've added a `__tostring()` function but I don't understand why it needs it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you use  Symfony's [`NumberType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html) instead your own.

Check the namespace at the top of `AdminController` file, which `NumberType` is being used.

If there's:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
```

then it means you're using wrong class.

It should be something like:

```
use App\Some\Namespace\To\Your\NumberType;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i'm using the good one `use App\Form\NumberType;`. I just figure this out, I renamed `NumberType` to `MyNumberType`  and everything is good for now :D